# Alt Beacon Parser is not working even after adding new parser layout

Tags: altbeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

Even after updating the beacon manager with new parser the scan-filter is still using old beacon parser and failing to parse.

The old beacon parser is

```
 beaconParserList: altbeacon, m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25
```

Setting new beacon parser

```
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25");
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(beaconParser);
```

Scan results after enabling debug on Alt-Beacon library

```
 D/BeaconParser: Processing pdu type FF: 0201061aff4c000215fb7dd88a496f42c49f4a382d8258b4ee03e8044ec41e09354141413d6d536d21366534563b74395a3d42497b2a4d6e417166474800 with startIndex: 5, endIndex: 29
 D/BeaconParser: This is not a matching Beacon advertisement. (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 0201061aff4c000215fb7dd88a496f42c49f4a382d8258b4ee03e8044ec41e09354141413d6d536d21366534563b74395a3d42497b2a4d6e417166474800
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your beacon parsers **after** you start scanning by calling `beaconManager.bind()` or constructing `RegionBootrap(...)`, then you need to manually apply your changes with `beaconManager.applySettings()`

While the above works, it is usually easier just to move the code that sets the beacon parsers above the code that starts scanning.